# Set PDF page numbering for scanned images that have double book pages in a single image

Tags: pdf, page-numbers

I've scanned a book and saved each scanned image in a .jpg format. In each image, there are two book pages. I know how to import all scanned images in one PDF file. What I'm trying to do is how to set a page number for each page that's convenient with the ***double pages in one*** fact. I'm using *Foxit PhantomPDF* to set page numbers through **Organize** > **Format Page Numbers**. How could I set the page numbering in order that when I type the page number in the page navigation bar, I get redirected to the page I'm looking for? I think one of the available solutions is to Image Edit the scanned images to make a single page in one. But unfortunately the image editing solution would take time. I'm looking for a solution with keeping images as is. I've searched for that but unfortunately none of my search results helped.

Comment: Dumb question: why did you save as .jpg? Assuming that there is a lot of (high contrast) text, JPEG is extremely weak, and produces lots of visible artefacts.

Comment: @MaxWyss thanks a lot for hinting that to me. I really have slight knowledge about the differences between image file types, so I think I've made a bad choice for the image file type to save my scans. Could you please suggest the best image file type(s) to save my scans in future?

Comment: If it is essentially text and line art, TIFF would be the choice. This would also make OCR easiest. If it is photographs, JPEG may be possible, but in order to get rid of screening, image processing would be necessary.